# Android bluetooth socket timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth

Maybe I miss something, but How can I change the timeout of BluetoothSocket.connect() ?

Thanks you

Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change timeout of BluetoothSocket.connect(). As documentation:

> This method will block until a connection is made or the connection
>   fails. If this method returns without an exception then this socket is
>   now connected.

A workaround.

Ex: timeout 5s.
Using CountDownTimer to check if connect is complete(success or fail). After 5s, if connection is incomplete then use BluetoothSocket.close() to cancel.

As BluetoothSocket documentation:

> close() can be used to abort this call from another thread.